# Proving Riemann Integrability

Tags: calculus

Prove that $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is integrable on $[0, 1]$.

Now for any given $0< \epsilon <1$ if we choose a partition of $[0, 1]$ as $[0, a]$ and $[a, 1]$ with $0<a< \frac{\epsilon}{4}$. Now for the interval $[a, 1]$, $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is continuous and so integrable so there exists a partition of $[a, 1]$ such that $U - L <\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Also on the interval $[0, a]$ the maximum value of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is $1$ and the minimum value of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is $-1$. So on the interval $[0, a]$ the difference between upper sum and lower sum is less than $2(\frac{\epsilon}{4})=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So the difference between upper sum and lower sum of the whole partition of the interval $[0, 1]$ is less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$. So $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is integrable on the interval $[0, 1]$.

Similarly, we can prove that if the given $\epsilon$ is greater than $1$ then by choosing a $0< \delta <1< \epsilon$ and proceeding as above.

Is My Proof Correct?

Comment: The function is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ as it is bounded and continuous except on a set of measure zero (its only discontinuity is at the point $x=0$). The approach with upper and lower darboux sums is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728620/is-fx-sin1-x-x-ne0-f0-0-riemann-integrable-on-0-1).

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$f:x \rightarrow |\sin(1/x) | $ is bounded by $1$ on $[0,1]$

$\forall x \in [0,1] :$ 
$$| sin(1/x) | \leq 1 $$

With this you can state that $\forall \epsilon \leq 1 $,

$$\int _{\epsilon}^{1}|\sin(1/x)| dx \leq 1-\epsilon \leq 1 < \infty$$

Therefore f is integrable on $[0,1]$

Comment: Is My Proof Correct??

Comment: Your proof is correct